# FFmpeg in Batch FOR Loop for MP3 Duration

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg, batch, mp3

I have a list of MP3s. I would like to see, onscreen and also in a file, one MP3 per line, with an indication of its duration. Here is the batch file I am using:

```
@echo off

cls
if exist MP3Duration.txt del MP3Duration.txt

for %%i in (*.mp3) do (
  echo %%i
  echo %%i >> MP3Duration.txt
  ffmpeg -i "%%i" | find "Duration" >> MP3Duration.txt
)
```

This has several problems: the output file contains filenames but no durations, and the screen display includes a lot of ffmpeg text and, for each file, an error: "At least one output file must be specified."

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg` console output is for informational purposes only and shouldn't be parsed with scripting. Use `ffprobe` instead:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams a -show_entries stream=duration -sexagesimal -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "%%i" | TEE.BAT -a MP3Duration.txt
```

Also see [FFprobe Documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) and [FFmpeg Wiki: FFprobe Tips](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips).

Comment: That helps. Thanks. Revised to include `-sexagesimal` (http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips) for desired output format, and Tee.bat (http://www.robvanderwoude.com/unixports.php#TEE) for simultaneous screen and text file output. Still not able to get filename and duration on a single line.

Comment: @RayWoodcock I missed the onscreen requirement. Not a Windows users, but a workaround could be to combine your `echo` and `ffprobe`, then just separately read the last line if you have `tail` or equivalent: something along the lines of `echo "$i $(ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams a -show_entries stream=duration -sexagesimal -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$i")" >> MP3Duration.txt; tail -n1 MP3Duration.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the media info in the following format :

```
1.mp3|00:33:11
2.mp3|00:34:28
3.mp4|00:04:18
4.mp4|00:02:18
```

Use the following code :

```
@echo off
>output.txt (
    for %%F in (*.mp3 *.mp4) do (
        for /f "tokens=2-5 delims=:., " %%a in (
            'ffmpeg -i "%%F" 2^>^&1 ^| find "Duration:"'
        ) do (
            set /p =%%~nxF^|<nul
            setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
            set /a "duration=1%%a*3600 + 1%%b*60 + 1%%c - 366100"
            REM echo !duration!.%%d seconds
            echo %%a:%%b:%%c
            endlocal
        )
    )
)
pause
```

This will log the results into the output.txt file, which can be opened in spreadsheet programs like excel, for processing further.

Comment: The console output from ffmpeg is not meant for machine parsing and can cause problems and errors. That's what ffprobe is for.

Answer (score 0):

```
rem this assumes ffmpeg is in c:\ffmpeg


if exist filelist.txt ( del /F filelist.txt )
if exist list.txt ( del /F list.txt )
copy nul list.txt >nul

rem change exts as needed for your audio files

    if exist *.mkv ( dir/b *.mkv >>list.txt )   
    if exist *.fl? ( dir/b *.fl? >>list.txt )   
    if exist *.avi ( dir/b *.avi >>list.txt )   
    if exist *.mp4 ( dir/b *.mp4 >>list.txt )   
    if exist *.mov ( dir/b *.mov >>list.txt )   
    if exist *.swf ( dir/b *.swf >>list.txt )

sort <list.txt >filelist.txt   


for /F "delims=;" %%F in ( filelist.txt ) do (
        for %%F in (^"%%F^") do (
            for /f "tokens=2-5 delims=:., " %%a in (
                'c:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg -i "%%F" 2^>^&1 ^| find "Duration:"'
            ) do (
                set /a full=%%a * 60 * 60 + %%b * 60 + %%c
            )
        )
        echo Length of %%F is %%a:%%b:%%c or !full! Seconds
)
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.